# React router dom passing data from parent component to child router component does not pass the props.match

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Content of the parent component App.js:-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Book from "./pages/Book";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "user/self", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => setUser(res.data));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <NavBar user={user} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route exact path="/book/:id" component={() => <Book user={user} />} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For the route :-

```
<Route exact path="/book/:id" component={() => <Book user={user} />} />
```

when i set the component value from component={Book} to component={() =>  i got an error :-

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

That is because i am using "props.match.params.id" inside the Book component.

How can i pass user state with props.match to he Book component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`component` prop isn't a function. Use `render` instead of `component` prop.

`render` prop is a function to which router props object is passed as an argument. You can pass these router props to your component.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/book/:id"
  render={(props) => <Book user={user} {...props} />} 
/>
```

See [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) for details on `render` prop

Comment: when console.log(props.user) in Book component i got in console undefined, while i passed the same 'user' state to NavBar component as you can see from my question, and i got a value of console.log inside NavBar component

Comment: make sure you aren't getting any error in the console while making the HTTP request. Also add a catch block at the end of the promise chain to catch any errors during the request

Comment: I am not getting any error, also i can see the user name successfully rendered in NavBar component

Answer (score 2):

This is how you use the component prop

`<Route exact path="/book/:id" component={Book} />`

consider using the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop like this:

`<Route exact path="/book/:id" render={(routeProps) => <Book user={user} {...routeProps} />} />`