# Obejct.assign not accepted in <Route> render callback (by TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Actually I have two questions for a `<Route>` like this in an *jsx* file:

```
<Route path={`${path}/some/thing`} render={(props) => (<MyComponent {Object.assign({}, props)} groups={groups} user={user} />)} />
```

### Why adding *props* at all?

In examples like [this it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542221/2092322) should look like `<MyComponent {...props} user={user} />`
But we can also see variants like [this](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#useparams): `render={({ match }) => <BlogPost match={match} />}`

Do we need the spread operator part `{...props}`, when the component uses multiple parameters?

### Why is *...* expected by Typescript?

For my code on top I am getting a TypeScript error at *Object*:

```
'...' expected.ts(1005)
```

Is there any way to use `Object.assign`, because the spread operator for objects is not supported by Safari 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{...props}` here is JSX syntax to pass all properties of the object `props` as React props ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)), so you cannot put arbitrary JavaScript/TypeScript expressions between these braces. Fortunately you don't need to because this JSX spread gets transpiled by TypeScript just like the rest of JSX. If you take a look at the `.JS` tab in this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gBUk64BeOACjBzBoC44A3jGAwANkn50owKgHMANHBgoARgEkqAEyQAPflQCuIFUigBfAJSsAfINJw4RGAahU4AHk3AAbg4EA6QK4IHjM4AHprAG5SMyigA), you will see there is no spread syntax in the JavaScript code, but just an `Object.assign` expression similar to your own.

Comment: Oh true, an object in an object literal doesn't make any sense! --- But actually, I should learn what the curly brackets in `<MyComponent {smth} />` really mean. It is rather a (code) block?

Comment: I am still wondering about the *props* part in `<MyComponent {...props} user={user} />`, because I've not detected it in the docs yet. What does it do? --- Ah I see in the docs you have referenced. I think, I don't need it at all in my scenario.

Comment: React-router passes the route props in this `props` object, so if you use `match`, `location` or `history` in your component you will need to pass them with `{...props}`, but otherwise you can leave it out. Also see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods

Comment: AFAIK you don't *need* to pass for example `match` with `{...props}`, as they show in the docs https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#useparams

Comment: If you use `component=` it gets passed automatically, but if you use `render=` you'll need to pass `match` etc. either with `{...props}`, or explicitly as `match={match}`, etc.